# how to setup encoding utf-8 in aspell (Linux)

Tags: aspell

this is quite (cough) simple (cough):
I need to set up the configuration of aspell to UTF-8

when I execute:

```
aspell dump config
```

get

```
# conf (string)
#   main configuration file
# default: aspell.conf

# conf-dir (string)
#   location of main configuration file
# default: /etc

# data-dir (string)
#   location of language data files
# default: <prefix:lib64/aspell-0.60> = /usr/lib64/aspell-0.60

# dict-alias (list)
#   create dictionary aliases

# dict-dir (string)
#   location of the main word list
# default: <data-dir> = /usr/lib64/aspell-0.60

# encoding (string)
#   encoding to expect data to be in
# default: !encoding = none
```

when I use aspell like this in an application executing:

```
cat skinnyFile.tmp | aspell -a --encoding=utf-8 --lang="es"
```

the output of some words like: "ahí" comes without the acute: "ah??"

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

1. aspell dump config > /etc/aspell.conf
2. chmod 644 /etc/aspell.conf
3. and open the `aspell.conf` file and change the line:

```aspell
# default: !encoding = none
```

to this

```
encoding utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience (with aspell 0.68), setting the `encoding` either with `--encoding` or in `aspell.conf` is not enough and might even be unnecessary. What definitely matters to aspell is that the `$LANG` environment variable is set to the locale corresponding to the dictionary you want to use. In this case you need to add to your `~/.bash_profile`

```sh
export LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
```

If you do not want to set this variable globally, write a launcher script for aspell that sets this variable.